# How can I inherit a message from another message in omnet++6 without getting an error?

Tags: omnet++

I have a message(myJob) derived from cPacket:

```
packet MyJob  extends omnetpp::cPacket
{
    int someField;
    string anotherField;
    double arrayField1[];
    double arrayField2[10];
}
```

My goal is to create another message derived from MyJob. For this purpose, I create another message from `Project->New->Messafe Definition(msg)` I select the `"Message that subclasses from a message defined in another .msg file"` option. And I got this in return:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "SomeMessage_m.h"
}}
packet SomeMessage;

packet MyMessage extends SomeMessage {
    int someField;
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile but it isi understandable because there is no `SomeMessage`, that's okay. Than I change `SomeMessage`s with `MyJob`s

```
cplusplus {{
#include "MyJob_m.h"
}}
packet MyJob;

//
// TODO generated message class
//
packet MyMessage extends MyJob {
    int someField;
}
```

But I got the same error as the one with `SomeMessage`.

```
'MyMessage': unknown base class 'MyJob' MyMessage.msg

MyMessage: base class is not a packet (must be derived from omnetpp::cPacket)   

Type declarations are not needed with imports, try invoking the message compiler in legacy (4.x) mode using the --msg4 option
```

How can inherit a message from another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper definition of a packet in OMNeT++ 6.0 should look like this:

```
// myjob.msg
packet MyJob {
  int someField;
  string anotherField;
  double arrayField1[];
  double arrayField2[10];
}
```

To create a packet derived from the above message one should write:

```
// mymessage.msg

import MyJob;

packet MyMessage extends MyJob {
  int someField;
}
```

Note that the filename of the base message has to match the parameter of `import`, according to OMNeT++ Simulation Manual:

> The import’s parameter is interpreted as a relative file path (by replacing dots with slashes,
> and appending .msg), which is searched for in folders listed in the message import path, much
> like C/C++ include files are searched for in the compiler’s include path

Comment: I tried your way. It worked after a sligth change. The include section starting with cplusplus {{ .. was necessary too. Otherwise I get an error when reaching MyJob's functions.