# Omnet 6.0.1 - Compilation error in code generated by opp_msgc

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am currently porting the SIMCAN simulator to omnet 6.0.1 and INET 4.4.

The current version of SIMCAN works fine with omnet 6.0 (pre-release 11). However, I got a compilation error in a class that is -- automatically -- generated by the opp_msgc tool (using omnet 6.0.1)

The code to define the SimcanPacket message (file SimcanPacket.msg) is the following:

```
cplusplus {{
    #include "Base/Messages/SimcanMsg.h"
}}

import inet.common.INETDefs;
import inet.common.packet.chunk.Chunk;
import SimcanMsg;

//
// Simcan packet to send data through sockets
//
class SimcanPacket extends inet::FieldsChunk{
    
    @customize(true);
    SimcanMsg *msg;
}
```

The code of the SimcanPacket class is the following (this is not automatically generated):

```
#ifndef _SIMCAN_PACKET_H_
#define _SIMCAN_PACKET_H_

#include "SimcanPacket_m.h"


/**
 * @class SimcanPacket SimcanPacket.h "SimcanPacket.h"
 *
 * Class that represents a Simcan Packet tos send message through TCP sockets
 *
 */
class SimcanPacket: public SimcanPacket_Base{


    public:

       /**
        * Destructor.
        */
        virtual ~SimcanPacket();


       /**
        * Constructor
        */
        SimcanPacket();

        virtual SimcanPacket_Base *dup() const;
};

#endif
```

In particular, opp_msgc compiles an inet::FieldsChunk subclass, which generates the following code (file SimcanPacket_m.cc):

```
void SimcanPacketDescriptor::setFieldValue(omnetpp::any_ptr object, int field, int i, const omnetpp::cValue& value) const
{
    omnetpp::cClassDescriptor *base = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (base) {
        if (field < base->getFieldCount()){
            base->setFieldValue(object, field, i, value);
            return;
        }
        field -= base->getFieldCount();
    }
    SimcanPacket_Base *pp = omnetpp::fromAnyPtr<SimcanPacket_Base>(object); (void)pp;
    switch (field) {
        case FIELD_msg: pp->setMsg(omnetpp::fromAnyPtr<SimcanMsg>(value.pointerValue())); break; // ERROR HERE!!!
        default: throw omnetpp::cRuntimeError("Cannot set field %d of class 'SimcanPacket_Base'", field);
    }
}
```

also, the following code is generated in the file SimcanPacket_m.h:

```
namespace omnetpp {

template<> inline SimcanPacket_Base *fromAnyPtr(any_ptr ptr) { return check_and_cast<SimcanPacket_Base*>(ptr.get<cObject>()); }

}  // namespace omnetpp
```

The error produced is the following:

```
src/Base/Messages/SimcanPacket_m.cc
src/Base/Messages/SimcanPacket_m.cc:457:36: error: call to deleted function 'fromAnyPtr'
        case FIELD_msg: pp->setMsg(omnetpp::fromAnyPtr<SimcanMsg>(value.pointerValue())); break;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/alberto/omnetpp-6.0.1/include/omnetpp/any_ptr.h:111:4: note: candidate function [with T = SimcanMsg] has been explicitly deleted
T *fromAnyPtr(any_ptr object) = delete; // =delete prevents undeclared specializations
   ^
src/Base/Messages/SimcanPacket_m.cc:503:36: error: call to deleted function 'fromAnyPtr'
        case FIELD_msg: pp->setMsg(omnetpp::fromAnyPtr<SimcanMsg>(ptr)); break;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/alberto/omnetpp-6.0.1/include/omnetpp/any_ptr.h:111:4: note: candidate function [with T = SimcanMsg] has been explicitly deleted
T *fromAnyPtr(any_ptr object) = delete; // =delete prevents undeclared specializations
   ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [Makefile:187: out/clang-release//src/Base/Messages/SimcanPacket_m.o] Error 1
```

and the contents of the file any_ptr.h is the following:

```
template<typename T>
T *fromAnyPtr(any_ptr object) = delete; // =delete prevents undeclared specializations
```

It seems that the generated code is using the template defined in the any_ptr.h file instead of the one automatically generated in the SimcanPacket.h file. Moreover, I noticed that pre-release 11 does not contain the file any_ptr.h.

How can I solve this error in my code? Any help is appreciated ;)

Thanks in advance.

Alberto

Comment: it is strange, you have a class for `SimcanPacket` but actually it generates `SimcanPacket_Base` object. Do you have a hierarchy? Please post a full code. Most likely a compiler tries to call `SimcanPacket_Base::fromAnyPtr` which is not defined, therefore it fails and tries to call `omnetpp::fromAnyPtr`, which is deleted and therefore you received the following compiler responses

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment gehirndienst! Indeed, SimcanPacket extends inet::FieldsChunk, and SimcanPacket_Base is automatically generated by  opp_msgc. I have coded the class SimcanPacket, which inherits from SimcanPacket_Base. I noticed that SimcanPacket class does not contain the fromAnyPtr template. Maybe this is the cause of the error... I have updated my first post to include this code. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

That is what I have expected. The inheritance should be defined at the declaration level (in `.msg` files) and not constructed artificially in the source code as you did. Declare your `SimcanBase` and derived `Simcan` packets in separate `.msg` files and generate the source code for each of. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72050256/12423880).